# Understanding bitwise comparisons between non-boolean parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm working with some old code, trying to improve it, and I came across the following, which I am having trouble understanding:

```
controlToUpdate.Font = 
    new System.Drawing.Font(someFont,
                            someFontSize,
                            controlToUpdate.Font.Style ^ 
                                (controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold));
```

Specifically, I am confused as to what the last parameter does. As I understand it, the following should do a bitwise comparison, and return the result:

```
controlToUpdate.Font.Style ^ (controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold)
```

..but what does that mean in this situation? What are the possible results, that may be passed as the third parameter to `new Font(...)`, and how can I rewrite this more clearly, while keeping with the intent of the original programmer?

*Sidenote: Is this a normal way to do things when working with Windows Forms? I'm a little new in that area - is the intent here obvious to coders more experienced in this field?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold
```

performs an "and" to return `FontStyle.Bold` if the style (`controlToUpdate.Font.Style`) includes bold, and `0` if the style does not include bold: basically, it gets just the "bold" bit.

```
controlToUpdate.Font.Style ^ (controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold)
```

performs an "xor"; if the bold bit was set, it removes it; if the bold bit was *not* set, then it does nothing (since "xor" with 0 is a no-op).

So basically, that complicated code just removes the "bold" bit (if it is set). A simpler implementation would have been:

```
controlToUpdate.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold
```

How that works: here, the `~FontStyle.Bold` *inverts* all the bits; `FontStyle.Bold` is `1`:

```
000....000001
```

so `~FontStyle.Bold` is:

```
111...1111110
```

we then "and" that with our current style, which means it keeps all of the old style ***except*** the bold-bit.

Comment: Excellent explanation! My "solution" will now be to wrap that operation in a simple helper-method, and call it something like `GetFontStyleWithBoldRemoved()` - just to be sure the next person catches it a little quicker. ;) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The [`FontStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx) enumeration is a [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) enumeration, making them into [bitmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap).

Using bitwise operators, allows you to find out which flags are "on", "off" and of course, change them.

This is very common - for example, to find out if the style is bold or italic, you would use:

```
FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is normal, or not, depends on what was the *reason* of doing this, but basically this means:

```
controlToUpdate.Font.Style ^ (controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold)
```

`(controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold)`: bitwise `AND`, so it's enough having a `0`, and it will return `0` (can think about this like a multiplication)

```
1 0 = 0
0 1 = 0 
1 1 = 1 
0 0 = 0
```

So `(controlToUpdate.Font.Style & FontStyle.Bold)` will return true, only if `controlToUpdate.Font.Style` is **Bold** too

after we have

`controlToUpdate.Font.Style ^`: a bitwise `XOR` operator, where the same value gives `0`

```
1 1  = 0 
0 0  = 0
1 0  = 1 
0 1 =  1
```

So, considering previous output (say it's a **Bold**) the result will be `false` or `0`,so **Regular** font style.

In practise, this is a way to enforse *Regular* type font, independently of the real style set on the control.